# Select records that match at least all items in a list

Tags: mysql, sql

Assuming that i have the following database table:

```
ID | Name    | Type     | Value|
--- --------- ---------- ------
1  | First   | A        | 10   |
2  | First   | B        | 20   |
3  | First   | C        | 30   |
4  | First   | D        | 40   |
5  | Second  | A        | 10   |
6  | Second  | B        | 20   |
```

and a previous query returned:

```
ID | Name    | Type     | Value|
--- --------- ---------- ------
1  | Third   | A        | 10   |
2  | Third   | B        | 20   |
3  | Third   | C        | 30   |
```

My question is:
What is the best way to query the first table and get all records that have at least all the **type** returned in the previous query?

In the above example the name "Third" has types A B C. Using these as a list, I would like to retrieve only the "First" records (as "First" has A B C D) but not "Second" (as "Second" has only A B - missing C).

The IN statement matches eveything, and I want the query to match at least all items in my "type" list. **The list is does not necessarily come from an sql statement but can be provided**

**EDIT:** I'm working with MySQL

Comment: Go on. Try something.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database that you are really using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Query

Included are two variations of the same query for either database.

---

#### MySQL

[DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qHbpYNYTyekxo4UMeHe8q2/0)

```
SELECT main.* 
FROM   main
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT name, json_arrayagg(type) as type
  FROM main
  GROUP BY name
) AS main_agg USING(name)

WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM (
    select json_arrayagg(type) as type
    from query 
    group by name
  ) AS query_agg
  WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(main_agg.type, query_agg.type)
)
```

- groups types by name
- uses the [JSON_CONTAINS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains) function to compare the table to the query

---

#### Postgres

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ff667/6)

```
WITH main_agg AS
(
  SELECT name, array_agg(type) "type"
  FROM main
  GROUP BY name
)

SELECT main.* 
FROM   main
JOIN   main_agg USING(name)
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM (select array_agg(type) "type" from query group by name) query_agg
  WHERE main_agg."type" @> query_agg."type"
)
```

- groups types by name
- utilizes the Array `@>` ([contains operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-array.html)) to compare to the query

---

### Setup

(Works for MySQL or PostgreSQL)

```
CREATE TABLE main
    (ID int, Name varchar(6), Type varchar(1), Value int)
;

INSERT INTO main
    (ID, Name, Type, Value)
VALUES
    (1, 'First', 'A', 10),
    (2, 'First', 'B', 20),
    (3, 'First', 'C', 30),
    (4, 'First', 'D', 40),
    (5, 'Second', 'A', 10),
    (6, 'Second', 'B', 20)
;


CREATE TABLE query
    (ID int, Name varchar(5), Type varchar(1), Value int)
;

INSERT INTO query
    (ID, Name, Type, Value)
VALUES
    (1, 'Third', 'A', 10),
    (2, 'Third', 'B', 20),
    (3, 'Third', 'C', 30)
;
```

Comment: Hello and thank you, i'm working with MySQL. It seems that it does not support WITH and EXISTS, i get some errors. How can this be written in MySQL?

Comment: EXISTS should work in MySQL and WITH queries can just be made sub-queries.

Comment: Can you help me with the sub-query please? I've tried and nothing comes out. The select 1 sub-query returns "1". I've also changed the array_agg to group_concat but didn't manage to connect the pieces

Comment: Which version of MySQL? 5.7 and newer supports JSON, so you could make use of json_arrayagg — older versions don’t support JSON. You’d also need to replace the contains operator `@>` with a MySQL equivalent.

Comment: I'm using 5.7.17

Comment: This is great, as i expected it! Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

In standard SQL, you can do this as a `join` and `group by` with some filtering.  The following assumes that the `type`s are unique for each name in each table:

```
with prevq as (
      . . .
     )
select t.name
from t join
     prevq
     on t.type = prevq.type
group by t.name
having count(*) = (select count(*) from prevq);
```

EDIT:

MySQL does not support CTEs (before 8.0).  This is easy enough to do without:

```
select t.name
from t join
     (<your query here>) prevq
     on t.type = prevq.type
group by t.name
having count(*) = (select count(*) from (<your query here>) prevq);
```

Comment: Hi and thank you, please see my comment at the other post.